# Getting header errors while trying to add mongoose subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am receiving the Error: `Can't set headers after they are sent`.  I know it's coming from this POST call, However, I cannot figure out where it's coming from.  Is there anyone who knows how to troubleshoot this?  For reference, address is a subdocument of member and both have mongoose definitions.  if someone could help me understand why this error is happening, I would be greatly appreciated.

```
.post(function(req, res) {
  member.findById(req.params.member_id, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
      return (err);

    new_address = {
      street1 : req.body.street1,
      street2 : req.body.street2,
      City : req.body.City,
      State : req.body.State,
      Zip : req.body.Zip,
      Lat : req.body.Lat,
      Lng : req.body.Lng
    };

    if(result.address === undefined){
      result.address.push(new_address);
    }
    else{
      result.address = [new_address];
    }

    result.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Address created!!!' });
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `res.send` and `res.json` can both execute in case there's an `err`

Try this

```
result.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        return res.send(err);

    res.json({ message: 'Address created!!!' });
});
```

Comment: That works now.  But I have a CastError Error now.  I'll ask another question for that one.  Thanks much.